# Using lifecycle policies in Google Cloud Storage, would imply early deletion charges if transition to Nearline to Coldline before 30 days?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have enabled versioning in my bucket, old versions would be deleted 14 days after being uploaded. With my lifecycle configuration, on day 15 data would be moved to Nearline and on day 30 to Coldline.

1. Does that makes sense from a cost wise perspective?
2. Would it be better to change to Coldline on day 45 so that it stays previously a minimum of 30 days in Nearline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a minimum of storage duration on Nearline of [30 days](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#nearline), so if you move the objects from Nearline to Coldline in 15 days it will be charged to you by the 30 days anyway.

The best to do from a cost wise perspective is to set the change from Nearline to Coldline to 45 days, so the objects can star on Nearline the 30 days that will be charged to you.

Comment: That's what I thought in the first term but it is confusing after reading other references: [Early deletion of Nearline Storage and Coldline Storage objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) . Also, have a look to this per second prorated mention: [Pricing notes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing). From what I'm undertanding, as long as you don't delete nor overwrite the object, you can change the storage class with lifecycle policies and being proratedly charged. Correct?

Comment: Actually, if you check on the following [note](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#overwriting_and_moving_objects), if you create a Nearline Storage object and 10 days later you change the storage class, you will be charged for the remaining 20 days of storage.

Comment: The question here is not for overwrites nor deletions, because that's clear in GCP documentation. Minimum of 30 days for Nearline and 90 for Coldline after upload the object. I'm referring to lifecycle management, if you read the first link provided before, it says that class storage transitions does not incur into charges for early deletion of ovewrites if you just changes from Regional to Nearline. Please, read that part carefully and let me know what you think. :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you use SetStorageClass you will keep the original creation day. So it would be the same if you change it on day 30 or day 45 (this will depend on your case scenario) and you won't have any charges for early deletion as says [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#early_deletion_of_and_objects)

Comment: Thank you Daniel, documentation is usually clear but it is frequently scattered. Gracias!